# problem on enable and disable GameObject

Tags: unity

I'm trying to enable and disable GameObject (canvas) using this code:

```
public int canvaslevel = 1;
public GameObject one;
public GameObject two;
public GameObject three;



void Update(){
    if(canvaslevel=1){
        one.SetActive(true);
        two.SetActive(false);
        three.SetActive(false);
    }
    if(canvaslevel=2){
        one.SetActive(false);
        two.SetActive(true);
        three.SetActive(false);
    }
    if(canvaslevel=3){
        one.SetActive(false);
        two.SetActive(false);
        three.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work!!!

error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to`bool'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `canvaslevel==1` instead of `canvaslevel=1`. Change to `canvaslevel==2` and `canvaslevel==3` as well.

You need to check equivalence not assign a value.